# angular.copy when array has custom property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, copy

Consider following example:

```
var ar = [4, 2, 3];
ar.$x = 'something';
var br = angular.copy(ar);
console.dir(br);
```

`br` does not have `$x` property any more, because when copying array, angular iterates with `for (;;;)` which does not see custom properties (if it iterated with `for in` then it would work).

Which of following shall I do?

1. Create array like class and then assign property;
2. If it's bug, report to angular;
3. Change my code, because assigning property to array is not good practice;

Comment: Why are you assigning a property to the array? This will help decide if 3 is true.

Comment: @sdgluck I'm assigning `$modified` property to array if something in it has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [angular.merge()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge) 
This is a deep copy that includes enumerable properties.

```
var ar = [4, 2, 3];
ar.$x = 'something';
var br = angular.merge([], ar);
console.dir(br);
```

Output

```
Array[3]
  0: 4
  1: 2
  2: 3
  $x: "something"
  length: 3
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: Hate to spoil the good mood, but `merge()` does **not** make a deep copy, it simply extends `br` with `ar`. If you afterwards change `ar`, say `ar.y = 'x'` then `br` will hold `y: 'x'` too. Proof of concept -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/idH8tKqRb2zGXT817UvV?p=preview**

Comment: **Good Catch**. My eagerness to match the OPs example resulted in omitting the new array to merge into. I have updated the answer with the correct code. `var br = angular.merge(ar)` should be `var br = angular.merge([], ar)`. Updated POC -> http://plnkr.co/edit/UOGX1CpoOfr0QA4YqNda?p=preview.

Comment: I ended up changing my code, but marked this answer because it solves problem that is in question.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's not an Angular problem. If you call such a statement:

```
ar.$x = 'something';
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(ar));
```

You will see that `[object Array]` will be logged. That is how `Array.isArray()` method works, and, in its turn, that is how angular `copy()` method decides how to iterate through the entity passed as the argument. This detection is crucial beacuse `for ... in` loop on an array can make some confusions in other cases. Here is described why: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

I would advise you to change your code, for this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery:

jQuery.extend([], ar);

```
var ar = [4, 2, 3];
ar.$x = 'something';
var br = jQuery.extend([], ar);
console.dir(br);
```